# What is the best way to identify unknown connectors?

Tags: connector

I'm having trouble finding a replacement connector, it's the same as the one in this picture, the picture only calls it a "mini 2 way 2.54mm pitch female connector" - lots of these exist, so can someone please tell me the technical name of this particular one?:

[image]

This sort of thing happens all the time, does anyone know of a master document of connectors I can use to identify things with?

Answer (score 1):

In the resource section on this page:
https://www.pololu.com/product/1168/resources
https://www.pololu.com/file/0J372/JST_eXH.pdf

this is **XHP-2**