# What does this power connector look like exposed?

Tags: connector

I'm trying to build a DIN rail power supply enclosure, and not wanting to reinvent the wheel, I did Google Images "din rail mounted power supply".

Many many listed units feature a power connector like the   following image...

[image: Typical DIN PSU connector]

I can't quite figure out what it is or find it in an electronics catalogue.  Is it mounted to the internal pcb?  Or is it plugged into another connector as you can see a break that might be another collar /socket.  Is there a wire on the internal side?

I'd appreciate either a verbal description or a link to a supplier's catalogue so that I can see for myself.  There must be loads as many of the images returned from my search featured this exact (down to the colour) connector.

I looked for guidance within [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/221017/what-is-the-best-way-to-identify-unknown-connectors) question but it was unfruitful.

Comment: At least one style of these are commonly called "Phoenix connectors" (for being made by Phoenix Contact). The screw terminal part is indeed a plug-in module. Unfortunately, Phoenix makes lots of products and I don't know what these ones are called/numbered to find them as parts — in other words, I want to know the answer to this question too!

Comment: Phoenix Euroblock

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are referred to as "Pluggable Terminal Blocks" and are manufactured by multiple companies

SPC technology, Phoenix connector, CAMDENBOSS, IMO PRECISION CONTROLS, MULTICOMP

[image]

http://uk.farnell.com/multicomp/mc000068/terminal-block-pluggable-6pos/dp/2008042

[image: http://uk.farnell.com/multicomp/mc000208/terminal-block-header-2pos-th/dp/2008197?MER=sy-me-pd-mi-acce]
http://uk.farnell.com/multicomp/mc000092/terminal-block-header-6pos-th/dp/2008068?MER=sy-me-pd-mi-acce

Answer (score 2):

It's definitely a two-part terminal block. One consists of a PCB-mounted "adapter" with large pins, and the other of the majority of the visible part as well as a protrusion that contains sockets that fit the pins of the other part. Phoenix Contact calls them ["PCB connectors"](https://www.phoenixcontact.com/online/portal/ca?1dmy&urile=wcm%3apath%3a/caen/web/main/products/subcategory_pages/PCB_plug-in_connectors_P-11-02/42d3a3f5-0788-4f1d-854e-6f898375f068).

[image: Phoenix Contact PCB Connector]

Comment: We live in a cut throat capitalistic society with many companies all vying to get ahead of one another by differentiating their products.  So how come they're all the same shade of green?

Comment: @PaulUszak - because if you really do want to differentiate your product you have to do all of your own marketing. But if you just copy someone else and make it cheaper ...

Comment: Surely mud grey is the cheapest colour?

Comment: @PaulUszak: Only if it's already being made in mud grey consistently. Otherwise it's cheapest to use the color that already exists.

Answer (score 1):

It was easy to locate on Digikey website.
You are correct that it appears to be two cascaded connectors.

Here is the external  [one.](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/on-shore-technology-inc/EDZ950-4/ED1719-ND/123871)

The internal is probably a PCB mounted header pin with adapter to,header socket using screw terminals.